# Why don't anonymous types have an indexer property?

Tags: c#, compilation, anonymous-types

Since anonymous types are compiler-generated anyway, why don't they go one step further with an indexer to access the values of its properties similar to ExpandoObject, but make it statically coded.

Some background:
I am currently trying to scrape up any last bit of performance I can in a microORM and one thing sticks out to me: reflection on anonymous types.

Parameters are passed in as an object which while not required to be an anonymous type typically is. I have to use reflection to get each member's name and value, because anonymous types are just compiler generated POCOs really.

After working with ExpandoObject and some of the other dynamic structures in C# I find myself missing Expando's explicit IDictionary interface implementation.

Comment: Anonymous types serve a very distinct purpose, one that has *very* little to do with what some C# programmers want them to do.  They power Linq, that's all.  Trying to make them do more is a fail whale.  Performance has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: I am well aware that they CANNOT currently do this and you are correct about the initial reason for creation of the construct, but I disagree that using anonymous types in anything other than linq is a 'fail whale'. They are a very big part of the language now.

Comment: The real fail-whale is having anonymous type's members have "internal" access only.  If you try this in Razor: @Html.Partial( "~/Shared/DatePicker.cshtml", new {id="ctrl1",mode="yearonly"} ), it will fail with a binding error, because the Razor engine cannot access the anonymous type's properties, even when the model is declared with @model dynamic.  The model is present and the property is visible in the debugger, but the default page binder as implemented by Razor will not try to access properties with reflection.  It still fails in similar fashion even if you pass an ExpandoObject instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [definition of ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see it implements IDictionary and IDynamicMetaObjectProvider (the magic piece that lets your code hook into the DLR). Basically it brings the power of [Python dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (dictionaries in Python can be accessed via a string-based "indexer" or using a . accessor as if it were attributes (or even functions) defined directly on the object).

Anonymous types aren't dynamic. They are resolved at compile time. You cannot add, or subtract to their definition.

In general, there is no "dictionary" type access to the reflection API although I don't see why you can't implement it. IDictionary is an interface...you could create an IDictionary implementation that takes an object and resolves the indexer requests using reflection on that object.

Answer (score 1):

They don't have an indexer because you have the parameter passed in as the base Object reference type. It is not a reasonable assumption that you could use methods defined on an interface that is not defined in the method contract.

Comment: Yes they are passed in as object, but if the anonymous type implemented an interface, performing an 'is' or 'as' operation would work, thereby exposing the contract.

Comment: err, I guess. As Hans suggests in the comment to the original question, that is not something you should use. The anonymous type is a POCO object as you have said, the ExpandoObject is a sealed class that implements IDictionary, ICollection<KeyValuePair>, Enumerable<KeyValuePair>, IEnumerable, INotifyPropertyChanged, and IDynamicMetaObjectProvider. ExpandoObjects would be great if you need those, but if you do not need those interfaces, then you are paying a large overhead for something you do not need. Use 'is' or 'as' to check for ExpandoObject if needed.